Dual boot (Windows 11 + Windows 11) keyboard issues
I have a peculiar problem, that is:
I have 2 copies of Windows 11 installed on my machine (separate sdd's)
Sometimes I am unable to select system to boot into - keyboard is not working...

It works when I am booting up from complete shutdown / power-off
It does not work when I select 'reboot' from either of installed os.

My PC spec:

motherboard - Asus x670 hero
keyboard - G915 from Logitech

Keyboard is connected using cable.
I tried to disable fast startup in both systems as well as in BIOS - no difference
Same goes for forcing legacy usb option in bios (with XHCI hands-off enabled).
I'm out of options right now - is there a solution for this?

Well, I managed to fix the issue - it seems that switching to another usb port solves this problem.
It is quite strange given that all of the ports are working correctly with full speed though...
Nevertheless - I choose another random free port and now system selection menu is responsive, at least for keyboard.
